# All the checkboxes appear checked. VueJs VueMaterial

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-material

I'm trying to check just one checkbox, but when I check it the rest become checked as well. Why does this happen? Any kind of documentation on this?

```
<md-layout v-for="Location in Locations" :key="Location.id">
  <md-checkbox v-model="checkbox" class="md-warn">{{ Location.city }}</md-checkbox>
</md-layout>
```

```
data () {
  return {
    checkbox: false,
    Locations: [{
      id: 1,
      city: '1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      city: '2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      city: '3'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      city: '4'
    }, {
      id: 5,
      city: '5'
    }, {
      id: 6,
      city: '6'
    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `v-model` for each checkbox is the variable `checkbox`, the value for that variable is being bound to each of the components. You want the `v-model` of each checkbox component to have its own variable to reference.

You could turn your `checkbox` Boolean into a `checkboxes` Object, with index keys for each location ID:

```
data() {
  return {
    checkboxes: {
      1: false,
      2: false,
      3: false,
      4: false,
      5: false,
      6: false,
    },
    ...
```

Then in your template, reference each `checkboxes` property value by the `Location.id`:

```
<md-checkbox v-model="checkboxes[Location.id]" class="md-warn">
```

---

Or, if you don't mind affecting the `Locations` data property, you could simply bind to a `selected` property of each location:

```
<md-checkbox v-model="Location.selected" class="md-warn">
```

Comment: GREAT!!
Works perfect! :) Thanks